# How to create an "image picker" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

guys.  I am a newbie at Objective-C programming.  I was wondering if it is possible to make an image that a user can pick from an image library on their phone.  I already have created a UIImageView in the storyboard and a UIImage in the code.  How should I do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "make an image that a user can pick"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Have you searched github and cocoacontrols for whatever it is you want to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the [UIImagePickerController class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) and set the source type to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`